How to add url segment automatically using baseref?
I have a Blazor server-side app and I added the following in _Host.cshtml:
<base href="~/Sub" />

I also changed the launchsettings.json:
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58014/Sub",
      "sslPort": 44309
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

My entry point is Home.razor with the following attribute:
@page "/"

I use either an anchor tag, NavLink or the NavigationManager to go to other pages, for example:
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" target="_self" href="/">Home</a>
</li>

or:
navigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true, true);

However the base ref is being ignored.
How can I make sure that the navigation automatically includes the base ref defined?
